# Android: made a text in RelativeLayout and can't change text in activity?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/text"
    android:textColor="#F0F8FF"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

This is declaration of the text field in `activity_main.xml`.
And the activity:

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
text.setText(napis);
```

Program crashes when I call `setText()` in `onReasume()` and it doesn't do anything when I call `setText()` in `onCreate()`.

Whole `xml` file as requested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    </FrameLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/zajebiste1" />

    <Chronometer       
            android:textColor="#F0F8FF"
            android:id="@+id/chronometer1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/text"
            android:textColor="#F0F8FF"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Activity:

```
text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
text.setText("Your Text");
```

Can't show more, cause something doesn't work... xf

`onCreate()`:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);  

       napis="Witaj!";
        //Remove notification bar
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
//,........
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        text.setText("Your Text");
        senSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        senAccelerometer = senSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        senSensorManager.registerListener(this, senAccelerometer , SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
       //set content view AFTER ABOVE sequence (to avoid crash)
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        // Create an instance of Camera
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        preview.addView(mPreview);

    }
```

`onReasume()`:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    senSensorManager.registerListener(this, senAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}
```

Comment: post the whole class where you implement the textview also the whole xml

Comment: Post the logcat so we can see what is the exception.

Comment: What type of variable is `napis` ?

Comment: string, napis = text in polish

Comment: i dont know how... :|

Comment: please post your whole `onCreate` and `onResume` methods

Comment: @user2088880 post the error message

Comment: there is no error message, just text wont change or app crashes when i achive to change the text

Comment: have you extend FragmentActivity ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what is up with

`//set content view AFTER ABOVE sequence (to avoid crash)
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` ??

Can you try doing

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, this);

 TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
 text.setText(napis); 

 setContentView(layout);
```

set the contentView only once, towards the end of the method..

Try this, then post logcat if it doesn't work

Comment: it seems like it's something wrong with the first line

Comment: now here is the problem, when starting app it changes the text to napis, but then when i try to setText again or changle napis to something else it crashes...

Comment: can you show how you do the 2nd `setText` ? also if my answer helped you, itd be awesome if you mark my answer as correct :)